The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'Error code: 'UNKNOWN', message='Unknown failure: '[CDS]close[0]
I'm building an android app with android studio code but i'm using a physical device, when i build and run on older androids like 5.0 i get this error. but it works on new android versions like 14.
i've tried reducing minSdk and also checked debug settings on the physical device

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please note, the problem is not in the code but when executed on older android devices, eg 5.0

Ditto. Seeing same issue, in my case on an older Android 5.1 phone. So please followup if you uncover anything useful.
[FWIW, IMO the Community bot responses here are really not helpful...]

I have the same issue.  I set up a virtual Android 5.0 device and the app loads OK, however on a physical device it does not and I get the same error.
Using compileSdk = 34, minSdk = 21, targetSdk = 33
package com.example.greetingcard

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.greetingcard.ui.theme.GreetingCardTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            GreetingCardTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting( "WORLD" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface( color = Color.Cyan ) {
        Text(
            text = "HELLO $name!",
            modifier = modifier.padding(24.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    GreetingCardTheme {
        Greeting("World")
    }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In the Android Studio Fox version, it is normal, but when upgrading Android Studio to Koala, this issue occurs. Android 5.1 devices have this problem, while Android 9 can be installed normally

The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'Error code: 'UNKNOWN', message='Unknown failure: '[CDS]close[0]''' List of apks: [0] '/Users/liuchen/Downloads/MPAndroidChart-master

To anyone reading this, I found a -not so elegant- solution:
If you try to install the debug APK produced by Android Studio to the actual 5.0 device on your own, by using "adb push" and "adb pm install -r -t"  you get a more informative error:
INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION  ... DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION
Ofcourse I was not using that permission and, some searching revealed that, using com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0 or older forces merging this permission to your APK and Lollipop devices do not like it as, somewhere else it was already defined.
Using com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0 will NOT duplicate this permission to your app.
But here is the strange part:
The resulting APK still does not install by the IDE but, but you can install it using adb on your own:
adb push MyApp-debug.apk /mnt/sdcard/
adb shell pm install -t -r /mnt/sdcard/MyApp-debug.apk
Conclusion:
My app using TargetSDK/CompileSDK 35, MinSDK 21, and  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0' was successfully installed with adb push/shell to an actual lollipop device.
Hope this helps people smarter than me to identify the actual root of the problem.
